# ANGULARJS 2 (TYPESCRIPT) + WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress, angular, typescript

How can i integrate **Angularjs2 App (TypeScript) in Wordpress Theme (Pages)**.

In version **Angularjs 1 its easy** cause we dont compile so we can use **JS and HTML direct into wordpress pages**

Since **Ang2** is  using **Typescript and AOT** for compilation how can we integrate SPA app in **Ang2** into wordpress?
And i dont want to use Angular Wordpress Themes, we have another theme to use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to explore the new Angular 6 elements features to accomplish this.

Install Angular CLI 6 and initialize the project

```js
npm i -g @angular/cli
ng new wordpressWebComponent --prefix custom
```

Add the elements

```js
ng add @angular/elements
```

Create the component and build using ng build and you should have html and java script similar to what angularJS produces. Once you have the HTML and .js files its similar to what you did with AngularJS

Comment: No way to accomplish that without upgrade angular cli version? currently i am using 5

Thanks

Comment: I will need to use webpack build to accomplish that also?

Comment: Upgrading from 5 to 6 shouldn't be a problem. Doubt if there are going to be any breaking changes. CLI 5 anyway comes with webpack. So if you are using 5, you might already be using webpack. Webpack is by far the most efficient module bundler for angular